# The webpack hot loader recompiles when the code changes But it is not reflected in output (app.js)

Tags: javascript

If I modify the jsx file 
Webpack is recompiled by hotloader

but It is not reflected in the output file
The output is the same as before.

But I do not know where the setup went wrong.

maybe Is the webpeck.config.js setting wrong?

C:\react_game_prac2\client.jsx

```
const WordRelay = require('./WordRelay');
const { hot } = require('react-hot-loader/root')
const React = require('react');
const ReactDom = require('react-dom');

const Hot = hot(WordRelay);

ReactDom.render(<Hot /> , document.querySelector('#root'));
```

C:\react_game_prac2\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>last word relay</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="./dist/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

C:\react_game_prac2\WordRelay.jsx

```
const React = require('react');
const { Component } = React;

class WordRelay extends Component {
    state = {
        word:'기차2',
        value:'',
        result:'',
    };

    onSubmitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.word[this.state.word.length-1] === this.state.value[0]) {
            this.setState({
                result:'딩동댕',
                word:this.state.value,
                value:''
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                result:'땡',
                value:'',
            });
            this.input.focus();
        }
    };

    input;

    onChangeInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({value:e.target.value});
    }

    onRefInput = (c) => {
        this.input = c
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <div>{this.state.word}</div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>
                        <input ref={this.onRefInput} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChangeInput} />
                        <button> 입력!!</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>{this.state.result}</div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = WordRelay;
```

C:\react_game_prac2\webpack.config.js

```
    output: {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename:'app.js',
        publicPath:'/dist/'
    },  // 출력
```

git :
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/react_game_prac2

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the doc it says `react-hot-loader` should be required before `react`.

Comment: I made a mistake after turning on the webpack hot loader server

Run index.html

I'm sorry.

Thank you for answer